# Reconstruct point in rectangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

I have the following problem:
I have $4$ points $A,B,C,D$ and one point $P$ in a rect.
Visualisation of the problem:

[image]

The flat distance(ignoring $y$) between $|B-A|=|C-D|=|C-A|=|D-B|$ is always $1$.
The point $P$ is always in the rect, but I only know it's $x$ and $z$ position and the $y$ position(height) is the value I'm trying to calculate.
How can I calculate $P_y$?

Comment: The problem is, this is NOT a planar rectangle, hence its surface is not well defined, unless you add some other info.

Comment: You are right. I solved the problem by using a bilinear interpolation.